# Django models filter objects for ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-models

For example I have a model:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        'Is active user?',
        default=True
    )
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        default=None,
        blank=True,
    )
```

How can I filter only active users in ManyToManyField?
(It won't work, just my ideas, ManyToManyField need Model in to=)

```py
queryset = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
friends = models.ManyToManyField(
    queryset,
    default=None,
    blank=True,
)
```

Comment: So you have a `User` and you want to retrieve its active friends?

Comment: I want, friends ManyToManyField can refer only on active users
```python 
friends = models.ManyToManyField(to=User.objects.filter(is_active=True), default=None, blank=True,
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with [**`limit_choices_to=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to) to limit the choices of adding an element to a `ManyToManyField`, so here you can implement this as:

```
class User(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        'Is active user?',
        default=True
    )
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        limit_choices_to={'is_active': True}
    )
```

This will filter the set of available `User`s in a `ModelForm` that you construct for that model, and in the `ModelAdmin` for that model.